# If cell A=x and cell D=x, autofill cell E with the next to cell A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im looking to apply a code that if cell matches Cell A then the address from cell B will automatically populate into the cell E next to it. any ideas?

[image]

Comment: VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH, XLOOKUP, take your pick.

Comment: And if the name is unique and you have the dynamic array formula, one can use FILTER

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, another good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VLOOKUP` function would do the trick in this case.

There are 4 arguments for the function:

1. the value to lookup
2. the range in which to look for the value
3. the col. from which to return the match (1 being the first column in the 2nd argument)
4. the type of match (TRUE = approximate, FALSE = exact)

See more detailed explanation [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function).

For cell E3 the formula should be: `=VLOOKUP(D2, $A$3:$B$6, 2, FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks so much for you help. it worked perfectly. im trying to find my feet with excel so i appreciate your support.